# GIT: Restoring untracked files after reverting to previous commit

Tags: git

I'm trying to restore untracked files that were deleted when I went back to my last commit.

I was in a hurry to revert to my previous commit after messing something up, so I used:

```
git reset HEAD --hard
```

and

```
git clean -fd
```

...The second command I didn't really intend to do, but I'd forgotten that I'd not started tracking a certain folder before my next commit. I put a few hours of work into the files in this particular folder--is it possible to get them back even though they were untracked? Thanks

Comment: ``git clean``, especially with ``-f`` is on one level with ``rm`` regarding the hesitance one should have when typing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the folder was untracked, then it's gone after a `git clean`. If you have a file backup, you can use that to restore your lost folder, otherwise you're out of luck I'm afraid.

Comment: Or trying some kind of undeletion software working on the filesystem level, if the files contents really are worth the trouble. Hopes are low though, I guess.

Comment: Ah thanks for letting me know. This is a good lesson for me... ALWAYS track new files and commit once a task has been completed.